# How to restrict index creation/deletion on Elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

How to authenticate/secure index creation/deletion operations in ElasticSearch 1.0.0 cluster? also would like to know how to disable delete index operation on ElasticSearch HQ plugin? I tried following settings in elasticsearch.yml file, but still allows user to perform the operations.

action.disable_delete_all_indices: true
action.auto_create_index: false

Apprrecaite any inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Write a custom `ConnectionPool` class and use that instead of the default connection pools that ship with the client and make auth parameters as mandatory.

Now you can authenticate user every time.

You can use **Pimple**, It is a simple PHP Dependency Injection Container

example:

```
$elasticsearch_params['connectionParams']['auth'] = 
                   array($collection['username'],$collection['password'],'Basic')
```